# How can I update a record of two specific column with a particular value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Change the total fee to 5000 whose STNO=1003, 1006, 1007

plz send me the exact query statement for this question......

Thanks,
Churchill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 update mytable set totalfee = 5000
 where stno in ('1003','1006','1007')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update [table] set [total fee]=5000 where STNO in (1003,1006,1007)
```